# How to replicate the blue rectangles in the modern CV casual template?

Tags: moderncv

I searched in the code and in the forums, but I can't seem to find how to pull such a trick. Help me, please.

And, in advance, thank you !

Comment: Are you referring to the blocks next to "Education", "Master thesis" and "Experience" in [this orange example](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples/template_casual_orange.pdf)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rules used by `moderncv` to the left of the section titles are nothing else but simple colored `\rule`s inside a `\parbox`, so you can imitate them quite easily, using for example (the `\parbox` in the original definition can be omitted and if no additional space to the right is required `\hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}` can also be omitted):

```
\newlength\hintscolumnwidth
\newlength\separatorcolumnwidth
\setlength\hintscolumnwidth{3cm}
\setlength\separatorcolumnwidth{10pt}

\newcommand\MCVrule{%
  {\color{color1}\rule{\hintscolumnwidth}{5pt}%
  \hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}}%
}
```

If you want to incorporate this to a document (not using `moderncv.cls`) to decorate the section titles, the above definition can be used with the help of the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package to produce something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0.22,0.45,0.70}% light blue

\newlength\hintscolumnwidth
\newlength\separatorcolumnwidth
\setlength\hintscolumnwidth{3cm}
\setlength\separatorcolumnwidth{10pt}

\newcommand\MCVrule{%
  {\color{color1}\rule{\hintscolumnwidth}{5pt}%
  \hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}}%
}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
  {\llap{\MCVrule}\thesection}
  {1em}
  {}
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
  {\llap{\MCVrule}}
  {0em}
  {}

\begin{document}

\section{A test numbered section}
Some test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text
\section*{A test unnumbered section}
Some test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text 

A single rule \MCVrule

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much ! I'm new to teX and this is a bit confusing. But you were of great help !